# Set google translate to translate name as it sounds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

Well I want to translate a person name from arabic or hebrew to english.
but if the name has a meaning, so the translation result will be the meaning, and not the name pronunciation, which is what I need.

Is there a way to tell google to translate just the pronunciation and not the meaning?

thanks

Comment: Is your question about [google cloud translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/overview)?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to tell Google to translate just the pronunciation and not the meaning? Google Cloud Translation api does not support this feature(transliteration).

However, there is a `feature request` filed for the [same](https://issuetracker.google.com/35900102). You can vote for this feature by clicking `+1` and `STAR` mark to receive updates on it.